# Unable to get assemblyFileBinding to compile

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I'm attempting to use the AssemblyFileVersion binding (as seen in the full WSX below). I always get this compilation error:

> error LGHT0298: Unresolved bind-time variable
>   !(bind.assemblyFileVersion.filMobiusExe)

Can you see something wrong? I've declared my referenced `filMobiusExe` as a .net assembly, which it is. Do I need to use some additional command line switch or extension? I'm using 3.10.2.2516. I use Heat to generate the AsiWix_Generated ComponentGroup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
         xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

    <Product
        Id="..."
        Name="MyStuff"
        Language="1033"
        Version="!(bind.assemblyFileVersion.filMobiusExe)"
        Manufacturer="Autonomous Solutions, Inc."
        UpgradeCode="...">

        <Package Id="*"
         InstallerVersion="200"
         Compressed="yes"
         InstallScope="perMachine"
         Description="My Stuff"/>
        <Property Id="TARGETSERVERADDRESS" Value="http://localhost:18080/"/>

        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" CompressionLevel="high" MaximumUncompressedMediaSize="10000"/>

        <Property Id="ARPNOREPAIR" Value="yes" Secure="yes" />
        <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="yes" Secure="yes" />
        <Property Id="MSIFASTINSTALL" Value="1" /><!-- disable restore point creation -->

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
                <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDirAsiRoot" Name="ASI">
                    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDirAsi" Name="Mobius">
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>

            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLDIRROOT" Name="ASI">
                    <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Mobius">
                        <Component Id="cmpMobiusExe" Guid="*">
                            <File Id="filMobiusExe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.AsiWixSourceDir)\Mobius.exe" Vital="yes" Assembly=".net"
                                    AssemblyApplication="filMobiusExe" ProcessorArchitecture="msil">
                                <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Name="Mobius" Description="Client" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Advertise="yes" Directory="ProgramMenuDirAsi" />
                            </File>
                            <File Id="filMobiusConfig" Source="$(var.AsiWixSourceDir)\Mobius.exe.config" />
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <Component Id="SetConfigToServerAddress" Guid="..." KeyPath="yes" Directory="INSTALLDIR">
            <Condition>TARGETSERVERADDRESS</Condition>
            <util:XmlFile Id="AppConfigSetServerAddress" Action="setValue" Permanent="yes"
                        File="#filMobiusConfig" Name="value"
                        ElementPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='ServerAddress'[\]]"
                        Value="[TARGETSERVERADDRESS]" />
        </Component>

        <Component Id="SetConfigToServerExe" Guid="..." KeyPath="yes" Directory="INSTALLDIR">
            <Condition>TARGETSERVEREXE</Condition>
            <util:XmlFile Id="AppConfigSetServerExecutable" Action="setValue" Permanent="yes"
                        File="#filMobiusConfig" Name="value"
                        ElementPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='ServerPath'[\]]"
                        Value="[TARGETSERVEREXE]" />
        </Component>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Mobius.Setup" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpMobiusExe"/>
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="AsiWix_Generated"/>
            <ComponentRef Id="SetConfigToServerAddress"/>
            <ComponentRef Id="SetConfigToServerExe"/>
        </Feature>

        <SetProperty Id="ARPINSTALLLOCATION" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" After="CostFinalize" />
    </Product>

</Wix>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use !(bind.fileVersion.filMobiusExe).

Comment: fileVersion succeeds, but that's not the version number that I want. My `AssemblyVersion` is different than my `AssemblyFileVersion`, and fileVersion returns the former. My assemblies all define both attributes.

Comment: set File/@Assembly to ".net" or "win32", then for the same file set File/@AssemblyApplication to the value for File/@Id.

Comment: Got it from
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/02/08/get-binder-variables-for-assemblies-without-installing-into-the-gac.aspx

Comment: To be clear, I was never able to make `assemblyFileVersion` work. `fileVersion` did start working for me after I got `Assembly=".net"` added to my main executable `File` declaration.